# kivy: possible to use buffer as image source?

Tags: image, buffer, kivy

I've got code along the lines of the following which generates a new image out of some existing images.

```
from PIL import Image as pyImage

def create_compound_image(back_image_path, fore_image_path, fore_x_position):

    back_image_size = get_image_size(back_image_path)
    fore_image_size = get_image_size(fore_image_path)

    new_image_width = (fore_image_size[0] / 2) + back_image_size[0]
    new_image_height = fore_image_size[1] + back_image_size[1]

    new_image = create_new_image_canvas(new_image_width, new_image_height)

    back_image = pyImage.open(back_image_path)
    fore_image = pyImage.open(fore_image_path)

    new_image.paste(back_image, (0, 0), mask = None) 
    new_image.paste(fore_image, (fore_x_position, back_image_size[1]), mask = None)

    return new_image
```

Later in the code, I've got something like this:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
img = Image(source = create_compound_image(...))
```

If I do the above, I get the message that `Image.source only accepts string/unicode`.

If I create a `StringIO.StringIO()` object from the new image, and try to use that as the source, the error message is the same as above. If I use the output of the StringIO object's getvalue() method as the source, the message is that the `source must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str`.

What is the proper way to use the output of the `create_compound_image()` function as the source when creating a kivy Image object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is a `StringProperty` and is expecting a path to file. That's why you got errors when you tried to pass `PIL.Image` object, `StringIO` object or string representation of image. It's not what framework wants. As for getting image from `StringIO`, it was discussed before here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/l-3FJ2mA3qI
- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/684

You can also try much simpler, quick and dirty method - just save your image as a tmp file and read it normal way.

Comment: Thanks, Nykakin. I'd like to avoid the tmp file approach in order to avoid the time-consuming I/O operations. Thanks for the links - it does seem a bit convoluted, although useful; I guess that the Texture approach, as suggested below, might be the more feasible option for this particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to just combine two images into one, you can actually just create a texture using [Texture.create](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.create) and blit the data to a particular pos using [Texture.blit_buffer](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.blit_buffer) .

```
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Texture

bkimg = Image(bk_img_path)
frimg = Image(fr_img_path)

new_size = ((frimg.texture.size[0]/2) + bkimg.texture.size[0],
            frimg.texture.size[1] + bkimg.texture.size[1])

tex = Texture.create(size=new_size)
tex.blit_buffer(pbuffer=bkimg.texture.pixels, pos=(0, 0), size=bkimg.texture.size)
tex.blit_buffer(pbuffer=frimg.texture.pixels, pos=(fore_x_position, bkimg.texture.size[1]), size=frimg.texture.size)
```

Now you can use this texture anywhere directly like::

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
image = Image()
image.texture = tex
```

Comment: I have a question about this method. When pasting into 'tex', it seems that rather than pasting into a blank surface, the program attempts to fill 'tex' with the pixels in 'bkimg' or 'frimg'; this, in turn, seems to scale 'tex'. Is there a way to simply make it act is if pasting into a blank canvas, as intended? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind - took care of it using pygame Surfaces. Thanks again!

Comment: glad to see you got it working. I seem to have omitted the `size` parameter from blit_buffer which would be useful in this case to achieve what you are after.